# Why do view controllers in my Storyboard keep disappearing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

The View Controllers in my Storyboard file keep disappearing.

As of now I have to press the up arrow and highlight over every single item to reinstate my view controllers.

What can I do to get rid of this problem and is there something else I can do to reinstate these disappearing view controllers onto my storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug... Usually i'm able to fix it by closing the storyboard and re-opening it.

Comment: Happens to me quite a lot. Sometimes when you click on anything the whole Storyboard vanishes, and as @Computer says re-opening it seems to sort it

Comment: Clicking on some item in a scene (in the Document Outline) will show it again. I get this bug a lot especially when I open up the storyboard in more than one tab.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix mine by resetting xcode completely. Try this: http://www.developers-life.com/uninstallresetting-xcode.html