# Xcode 5: Images disappear in storyboard when switching view between ios6 and ios7

Tags: ios, xcode

When switching Storyboard views ( the "view as" in file inspector) between iOS6 and iOS7 to see how the images look on both iOS version, all of my images in both iOS versions disappears. I do not what is causing this. Is this some kind of glitch or bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that i have encountered. All you need to do is close the tab for the storyboard and reopen it, the images will show back up. You can also click on your controller in the left menu and it will show back up. You can view my answer from this questions [Why do view controllers in my Storyboard keep disappearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520641/why-do-view-controllers-in-my-storyboard-keep-disappearing/9520665#9520665)